# How can I beautify Json output in a discord.py bot message

Tags: python, json, python-requests, discord.py

First of all, I'm new here (first post) and new at python

I'm coding a discord bot that make a call to the API which fetch an http request for my game server.
The API output is printing with indent and its all good, but the discord bot message is all messed up like this.
How can I fix it?

Also, I can't access individual lines to print out like 'name' or 'maxplayers'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmiIu.png)

This is the api code to request and format json:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://vrising-server-scanner.p.rapidapi.com/179.155.101.206/27016"
headers = {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "03ceea7e11mshe52b1b49827f626p17aa4djsnb92582243b8e",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "vrising-server-scanner.p.rapidapi.com"
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = response.json()
json_formatted = json.dumps(data, indent=4)

 
print(json_formatted)
```

My discord code to send the output from API:

````
@client.command()
async def status(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Checking status...')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send('Status:')
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    await ctx.send('```')
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    await ctx.send(subprocess.check_output(['python', 'VrisingAPI.py']))
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    await ctx.send('```')

client.run(TOKEN)
````

Comment: You surely don't want to expose JSON to your client users anyway, right?  You want to pull information from that structure, and display the information.  The issue here is that `subprocess` returns a byte string, not Unicode.  Do `ctx.send(subprocess.check_output(,,,).encode('UTF-8"))` and you should see prettier results.

Comment: Please post the code or error as text in question, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven’t defined any special encoding to `check_output()` it will always return a `bytes` object by default. You can use `UTF-8` as an encoding in your case:

```
subprocess.check_output(['python', 'VrisingAPI.py'], encoding='UTF-8')
```

Another possible solution is to decode it manually using `bytes.decode()`:

```
subprocess.check_output(['python', 'VrisingAPI.py']).decode("utf-8")
```

If you are using Python 3.7 or higher you can also set the argument `text` to `True`, this will decode it using your system's default coding:

```
subprocess.check_output(['python', 'VrisingAPI.py'], text=True)
```